# Making android custom drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

[image: drawable]

How can one create such a drawable that will be matching height of given layout ? I know I have to create a some sort of multiple shapes within one drawable but I am kinda lost in this.

Comment: Simply use a 9 patch. Just stretch the vertical segment, Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:paddingTop="4dp">
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="90" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="1dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:height="8dp" android:width="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" android:height="4dp" android:width="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I solved it back then with custom view and overriding onDraw function. But thanks for xml solution. Might help somebody :)

Answer (score 2):

Try layer-list of 2 oval shapes and a line. Then set as the background of your view. I'm not sure if it works.

You can also use 9 patch: [read this](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)